# Java - JDBC - Access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem with connecting to online database with JDBC.

This is a list of what I have done up to now:

- I have created a data base,
- I have created a data base user,
- I have add this user to database with all privileges,
- After that I fill my data base with data using Import option and .sql file:

http://www41.zippyshare.com/v/70987939/file.html

When I want to connect to my database I get an error:

**Access denied for user 'user_name'@'xx.xx.xx.xxx' (using password: YES)**
.
Where xx.xx.xx.xxx is IP adress

Here is a code of my **connecting method**:

```
public String connectWithDataBase(int type) throws SQLException {

    String user = DB.login.getLoginData(type).getLogin();
    String password = DB.login.getLoginData(type).getPassword();


    String result = null;
    connectionStatus = false;

    if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
        try {

            Class.forName(DB.baseConfig.DATA_BASE_DRIVER_NAME).newInstance();

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    DB.baseConfig.DATA_BASE_ONLINE_URL, user, password);

            operation = connection.createStatement();

            result = "Connecting succesfull!";
            connectionStatus = true;

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            result = "Driver error.";
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            result = "Can't connect to database.";
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) 
        {
            result = "Conection error.";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

A body of class with **Config**:

```
// Name
public final String DATA_BASE_ONLINE = "xxx_zzz";

// Config data
public final String ONLINE_DATA_BASE_PORT = "xxx.yyy.pl:3306";
public final String ONLINE_DATA_BASE_TYPE = "mysql";
public final String ONLINE_DATA_BASE_DRIVER_NAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public final String ONLINE_DATA_BASE_ENCODING = "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"; // B. WAŻNE!!!

// Online base URL:
public final String DATA_BASE_ONLINE_URL = "jdbc:" + ONLINE_DATA_BASE_TYPE + "://" 
    + ONLINE_DATA_BASE_PORT + "/" + DATA_BASE_ONLINE + ONLINE_DATA_BASE_ENCODING;
```

And class with **Login Data**:

```
// Base users types    
public final int ONLINE = 0;

// User type --> loging data
private final HashMap<Integer, FlowLoginData> loginData = new HashMap<>();

// Nazwa tabeli
private final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

// Pola w tabeli
private final String TABLE_USERS_ID = "id";
private final String TABLE_USERS_PESEL = "pesel_number";
private final String TABLE_USERS_PRIV = "priv_level";
private final String TABLE_USERS_ONLINE = "is_online";

// Zmienna pomocznicza
private final String DASH = "'";

public DBLogin() {

    loginData.put(this.ONLINE, new FlowLoginData("user", <-- "user" was added to base
            "xxxxxxxxx"));
}
```

Could someone tell me where is mistake?

Comment: I don't think yout problem is with SQL but with java. Can you please show us your code and how you configure the user name?

Comment: At the moment it's hard to tell where your mistake is. Can you provide the code you use to connect to your database?

Comment: How do you connect to the database in your java code? Is the connection properties (url, username, password) configured in a properties file, are you using Spring? As mentioned before, code would be nice.

Comment: Have you flushed priveleges after you had created your user via `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`? You can check the actual privileges via `select * from information_schema.user_privileges;`

Comment: One moment! One information was erroneous - user_name is the same like this in database...

Comment: I can't do it because i get next error:  #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation

But I can check it:

GRANTEE: 'zzzzz'@'localhost' <- another user name 'zzzzz'
TABLE_CATALOG: def
PRIVILEGE_TYPE: USAGE
IS_GRANTABLE: NO